# Are Maybes a good pattern for scala?

Tags: java, scala, null, option-type, scala-option

For a while I have been struggling to integrate scala with java methods that might return null.  I came up with the following utility which helps a lot:

```
// produce an Option, nulls become None
object Maybe {
    def apply[T](t:T) = if (t==null) None else Some(t)
}

Maybe(javaClass.getResultCouldBeNull()).map( result => doSomeWork(result) )
```

I have a few questions about this solution:

1. Is there a better or more standard pattern to use?
2. Am I duplicating something that already exists?
3. Does this functionality have hidden gotchas?

Comment: Thanks!  I've been working in 2.7 and didn't realize that Option.apply() existed in 2.8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala's built-in [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Option.html) is what you're setting out to reinvent.

In that case:

```
scala> val sOpt: Option[String] = Option(null)
sOpt: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: He knows about the Option class already. He wants a function that makes the conversion easy.

Comment: `val sOpt1: Option [String] = None` and 
`val sOpt2: Option [String] = Some ("foo")` should do it.

Comment: better: `def mb (s: String) : Option [String] = if (s != null) Some (s) else None` would do it on 2.7.7

Comment: @Thomas: So many things are so much better in 2.8. This is just one among many.

Comment: @Randall Can't wait for it to come out. But since I have a application in "production", I'm still on 2.7.7.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother making a whole companion object out of it? It's just a function, so you don't need to implement it as an object that looks like a function.

```
object MyUtilities{
  // a whole bunch of other utilities that you use all over can also be put in this class.
  def maybe[T](t:T) = if (t==null) None else Some(t)
}
```